# Change the extension of a picture to phm in Java

Tags: java

If the filename is not the empty string, the method should also save the image in the corresponding
file as a PGM image.
How can I do that in Java?

Comment: I don’t think Java has a built-in writer for PGM, but [the format is very straightforward](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html).  It’s all ASCII text.

Comment: Hi Michalis, I see that you are new to stackoverflow.  Welcome!  When I read your question, I have a hard time understanding exactly what you are after.  Do you have an existing file that you want to rename?  Do you want to change the format of an image stored in the file?  Is there a specific library you are using or contemplating?  The more specific, the better.  Good luck!

Comment: Also you should research the difference between *file format* (how data is layed out in the file) and *extension* (the end of the file name like ".txt")

Comment: This is a very open ended question. What have you tried so far?